# How can I close all but one instance of R for installing tidyverse package correctly (without error)?

Tags: r, installation, package, tidyverse

I am trying to install the `tidyverse` package in Rstudio, but I got the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.6 is required.

I searched on many websites on the internet, I found an answer which seems to be correct, but I do not understand its explanations. The answer says that:

<<<You've probably got more than one instance of R running with those `tidyverse` packages loaded. Not sure about other operating systems, but on Windows, if these packages are being used, then those DLL files will be in use and you cannot delete them, which is what the `install.packages()` function will try to do.
So, just close all but one instance of R, maybe restart the computer just to be sure, and try again.>>>

Unfortunately, I don't understand what does "all instances of R" mean? And how I can close all but one instance of R?

Thank you in advance for your response.

I should say I have two different versions of R (`R i386 4.0.2` and `R x64 4.0.2`) and one Rstudio on my laptop. I want to install `tidyverse` package in my Rstudio.

**Edition:**

The result of run `dput(loadedNamespaces())` is in the following:

```
> dput(loadedNamespaces())
c("compiler", "graphics", "tools", "utils", "yaml", "grDevices", 
"stats", "datasets", "methods", "base")
```

Comment: make sure you didn't open `RStudio` or `R` many times : you could check in Task manager

Comment: @Walid, how can I check it using Task manager?

Comment: On which system are you working?

Comment: @Walid, I am using windows 10.

Comment: `ctrl+alt+del` `Task manager`

Comment: @Walid, I closed all programs through `Task manager`, and re-open `Rstudio` to install `tidyverse` package, unfortunately, I have still gotten the above error (in my question).

Comment: ,I fear  I won't be able to help more

Comment: Please try restarting your R session, e.g. using ctrl + shift + F10 in RStudio, then run `dput(loadedNamespaces())` and add the output to your question. This will tell us which packages are getting loaded when you start a fresh R session and perhaps help find a solution to your issue.

Comment: @BluVoxe, I added the result of `dput(loadedNamespaces())` to my above question.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't look like `vctrs` is loaded based on your `loadedNamespaces()` output. Try running `install.packages("tidyverse")` again having restarted your R session. If the issue persists, try running `install.packages("vctrs")` and then try again.